# Is it okay to throw an app specific exception from inside a custom shared library?

Tags: java

I want a shared library to wrap the exceptions from within and re-throw it as an application specific exception for those that can't handle them.

What I currently have is a library exception with a static method that sets the application specific exception class that I instantiate via reflection in case a exception being thrown.

My goal is to have a single app specific exception that can be handled gracefully by a common code.

Is there a better way to do this?

lib.LibExUtil.java

```
class LibExUtil {
  static Class<? extends RuntimeException> ex = RuntimeException.class;
  public static setAppEx(Class<? extends RuntimeException> ex) {
    this.ex = ex;
  }
  static RuntimeException wrap(Throwable t) {
    return (RuntimeException)ex
      .getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[] {Throwable.class}).newInstance(new Object[] {t})
  }
}
```

lib.SomeUtil.java

```
static void utilMethod() {
  try {
    // code with checked exception
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    throw LibExUtil.wrap(ex);
  }
}
```

myApp.MyAppEx.java

```
public class MyAppEx extends RuntimeException {
  MyAppEx(Throwable t) {super(t);}
}
```

myApp.Client.java

```
// initialization
LibExUtil.setAppEx(myApp.MyAppEx.class);  // optional

void method() {
  SomeUtil.utilMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For maintainability you generally want to avoid app specific functionality in a shared library.

It would make more sense to throw a library specific exception and wrap it at the app level if that is your use case.

Library exception:

```
public class LibraryException extends Exception {
    LibraryException(Throwable t) {super(t);}
}
```

lib.SomeUtil.java

```
static void utilMethod() {
  try {
    // code with checked exception
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    throw new LibraryException(ex);
  }
}
```

myApp.Client.java

```
void method() {
  try{
    SomeUtil.utilMethod();
  } catch (LibraryException e) {
    throw new MyAppEx(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to add, this method allows anything that uses your shared library to handle the exception in a manner appropriate to that component. Later on, you may want one component to throw a RuntimeException on the failure of utilMethod(), another to handle the exception and move on, then another to just throw the LibraryException up to a higher level component. The more granular your exception handling, the easier it is to debug an issue as your project gets bigger.

Comment: App specific functionality cannot be in shared library, but are runtime values included?  What if the shared library is never going to be run with multiple apps in the same jvm?  I wanted to make the client calls cleaner by not having to deal with the checked util exception directly.  I'll update the question with details shortly.

Comment: I am trying to avoid the bloat with the try-catch block, util calls are one-liners normally.

Comment: Hmm, I understand wanting to keep the util call a one liner. To correct myself, when I said app specific functionality, I was more so referring to the library having no contextual knowledge of the app. It really comes down to your abstraction level, the reason for the exception, and what is receiving the exception.

Answer (score 0):

In your example your library method SomeUtil.utilMethod(); has done some work and which resulted in an exception. It would be better that util method through some library defined exception alert the user that what went wrong with it.

Another issue is in case of multi project setup like maven if one module wants to throw a different exception then other module and the developer forgets to call static method then your library method will throw some misleading exception. Avoid this pattern.

Comment: It does alert the app with the `app ex` or possibly `lib defined exception` with the original ex wrapped inside.  In multi project setup, wouldn't each project have their own jvm instance to work with? Pardon my ignorance, but the multi project modules I know of, like in java ee examples are run separately.

Comment: Well I meant that if you have a maven like project where you have multiple modules where multiple modules are using your library method but may want to throw different exception based on their requirement. For e.g. module A: wants to throw some ModuleAException, module B: wants to throw ModuleBException and they both are part of same application running under same JVM.